# After finding max value, Find succeeding min value in separate column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

In my dataframe, I have these columns.

Date
Time-(5 min buckets 7:00, 7:05, 7:10 etc....)
High
Low

What I would like to do is to find the max in the 'High' column, THEN the min in the 'Low' column that proceeds it.

Take that difference, so essentially High-Low, and pass that to a new column that is saying

"If the 'High'.max is in the 7:20 row and the low is in the 7:50 row what is the difference, and place that difference on the row next to 7:20"

At the end of all of this, I'd like to have the mean or median for all the 'High' - 'Low' differences by 'Time'

For Example (from large dataframe)

```
           Date   Time   Ticker     High      Low    Range
0      01/02/18   7:05  USD/JPY  112.170  112.150
1      01/02/18   7:10  USD/JPY  112.175  112.140
2      01/02/18   7:15  USD/JPY  112.185  112.170
3      01/02/18   7:20  USD/JPY  112.180  112.155   112.180-112.080 = .10
4      01/02/18   7:25  USD/JPY  112.160  112.145
5      01/02/18   7:30  USD/JPY  112.160  112.155
6      01/02/18   7:35  USD/JPY  112.160  112.120
7      01/02/18   7:40  USD/JPY  112.145  112.100
8      01/02/18   7:45  USD/JPY  112.120  112.085
9      01/02/18   7:50  USD/JPY  112.155  112.080
10     01/02/18   7:55  USD/JPY  112.150  112.130
32898  07/05/19  11:35  USD/JPY  108.545  108.525
32899  07/05/19  11:40  USD/JPY  108.550  108.535
32900  07/05/19  11:45  USD/JPY  108.560  108.530   108.560-108.525 = .035
32901  07/05/19  11:50  USD/JPY  108.550  108.540
32902  07/05/19  11:55  USD/JPY  108.535  108.525
32903  07/05/19  12:00  USD/JPY  108.550  108.530
32904  07/05/19  12:05  USD/JPY  108.555  108.530
32905  07/05/19  12:10  USD/JPY  108.560  108.540
32906  07/05/19  12:15  USD/JPY  108.560  108.540
```

Desired output

```
Time    Range (median or avg for all of the instances where the Max High was 7:20 ect)
7:20    .10
11:45   .035
```

Do I use a Lamdba to make sure I'm only finding the Low.min after finding the High.max for each day?

I know I can group by 'Date' and find the max for each date.

```py
#High grouped by Date
df2 = df.loc[df.groupby('Date')['High'].idxmax()]
```

And I can find the range, but need the range AFTER finding the High.max then find the Low.min for each date, then by time.

```py
#Difference between High and Low
range = (df['High']-df['Low'])
```

But I don't know how to find the min after finding the max and returning that difference to where the max time happened

Comment: *If the high.max is at 8.05... then put it next to row 8:00` Doesn't look like that in your example: max is at `7:15` but you took the value of `7:20` and put the result at `7:20`.

Comment: Ahh sorry I will fix it, wrote it before I pulled an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the min **after** the max you can filter the rows within the groupby groups:

```
df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda x: x.High.max() - x[x.index > x.High.idxmax()].Low.min())
```

Result:

```
Date
01/02/18    0.105
07/05/19    0.035
```

In order to verify that this works correctly, you'll have to set e.g. the Low of the first row to 112.000, i.e. to make the day's absolute min occure before the max.

If you need the time info too, convert this to a dataframe and insert the time column:

```
res = df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda x: x.High.max() - x[x.index > x.High.idxmax()].Low.min()).to_frame('Range')
res.insert(0,'Time',df.loc[df.groupby('Date')['High'].idxmax(),'Time'].values)
```

Final result:

```
           Time  Range
Date                  
01/02/18   7:15  0.105
07/05/19  11:45  0.035
```

**UPDATE**
If you'd rather like to insert the ranges as a new column in the original dataframe:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Date')['High'].idxmax().values,'Range']=df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda x: x.High.max() - x[x.index > x.High.idxmax()].Low.min()).values
```

Output:

```
           Date   Time   Ticker     High      Low  Range
0      01/02/18   7:05  USD/JPY  112.170  112.000    NaN
1      01/02/18   7:10  USD/JPY  112.175  112.140    NaN
2      01/02/18   7:15  USD/JPY  112.185  112.170  0.105
3      01/02/18   7:20  USD/JPY  112.180  112.155    NaN
4      01/02/18   7:25  USD/JPY  112.160  112.145    NaN
5      01/02/18   7:30  USD/JPY  112.160  112.155    NaN
6      01/02/18   7:35  USD/JPY  112.160  112.120    NaN
7      01/02/18   7:40  USD/JPY  112.145  112.100    NaN
8      01/02/18   7:45  USD/JPY  112.120  112.085    NaN
9      01/02/18   7:50  USD/JPY  112.155  112.080    NaN
10     01/02/18   7:55  USD/JPY  112.150  112.130    NaN
32898  07/05/19  11:35  USD/JPY  108.545  108.525    NaN
32899  07/05/19  11:40  USD/JPY  108.550  108.535    NaN
32900  07/05/19  11:45  USD/JPY  108.560  108.530  0.035
32901  07/05/19  11:50  USD/JPY  108.550  108.540    NaN
32902  07/05/19  11:55  USD/JPY  108.535  108.525    NaN
32903  07/05/19  12:00  USD/JPY  108.550  108.530    NaN
32904  07/05/19  12:05  USD/JPY  108.555  108.530    NaN
32905  07/05/19  12:10  USD/JPY  108.560  108.540    NaN
32906  07/05/19  12:15  USD/JPY  108.560  108.540    NaN
```

Comment: When I run your code, it doesn't seem to change any of the df? When I print (df), it just prints the original dataframe etc... The output you are showing looks promising to me. Any suggestions as how to make this work?

Comment: @blankslatecoder No, it creates a new Series (upper part) or DataFrame (lower part), respecitvely. as you wrote in your question as desired output. See my updated answer for inserting the values in the original dataframe.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'm very new to this. The lower part did give me the same output as yours. I'm going to work on now achieving output similar to this.                                                            Time  Range
Date                  
01/02/18   7:15  0.105
07/05/19  11:45  0.035

Comment: ```python df2 = df.groupby('Time', as_index=False)['Range'].mean() ```  I ended up doing this, only thing I could figure out since I'm new to python

Comment: @blankslatecoder You're welcome. If this solved your problem, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like I already comment that the first max occurs at `7:15`, not `7:20`. Anyhow, here's my approach:

```
new_df = df.groupby('Date').agg({'High': 'idxmax', 'Low':'min'})

# copy the time
new_df['Time'] = df.loc[new_df.High, 'Time'].values

# compute the range
new_df['Range'] = df.loc[new_df.High, 'High'].values - new_df.Low

new_df.drop(['High','Low'], axis=1)
```

gives:

```
           Time  Range
Date                  
01/02/18   7:15  0.105
07/05/19  11:45  0.035
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, it was my mistake. Your code works to find that days range, however I'm looking for the 'Low' 'min' that occurs after the 'High' max.